# how to run google script only when cell c2 in sheet "Daily #s WK1" is changed

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, tabs, cell

i need a script that can run only if cell c2 in sheet "Daily #s WK1" is changed this is the code i have  it open and closes cells

```
 function onChange() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Daily #s WK1");
  var currentRange = ss.getRangeByName("NamedRange1");
  var rangeStart = currentRange.getRow();
  var values = currentRange.getValues();
var index = 0, rows = 1;
  var show = !(values[0][40] == "" );
for (var i = 1, length = values.length; i < length; i++) {
if (values[i][0] == 1 ) {
if (show) {
 sheet.showRows(rangeStart + index, rows);
 show = false;
index = i;
rows = 1;
} else
rows++;
} else {
if (show)
 rows++;
else {
sheet.hideRows(rangeStart + index, rows);
show = true;
index = i;
rows = 1;
}
```

Comment: its for google sheets

Comment: it runs when ever anything is edited i need it to run only when c2 changes

Comment: I do not work with js, check the FAQs if there is worksheet change event. In VBA we use `Worksheet_Change` event for trapping such changes. Here is a [VBA example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/why-ms-excel-crashes-and-closes-during-worksheet-change-sub-procedure/13861640#13861640)

Comment: @jeremylessig how is C2 changed ? Do you edit it manually or it is changed via a function for example ?

Comment: It is a data validation cell I click and change. I would use simple on edit or on change trigger but that fired all the time I need it to only fire when that cell is changed.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

You have to make use of the **event** handled by your function in order to check the current cell edited. As per the [Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) says:

> The onEdit(e) trigger runs automatically when a user changes the value of any cell in a spreadsheet. Most onEdit(e) triggers use the information in the event object to respond appropriately.

I suggest you to use the following code.

Bear in mind:

- [Simple Triggers Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)

### Code

```
function onEdit(e) {

  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === "C2" &&  e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Daily #s WK1") {
    // Your code
  }
}
```

### Reference

[Apps Script: Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)